# SQL query: convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, postgresql, sqldf

I'm trying to read a column from a database using a SQL query. The column consists of empty string or numbers as strings, such as

```
"7500" "4460" "" "2900" "2640" "1850" "" "2570" "9050" "8000" "9600"
```

I'm trying to find the right sql query to extract all the numbers (as integers) and removing the empty ones, but I'm stuck. So far I've got

```
SELECT * 
FROM   base 
WHERE  CONVERT(INT, code) IS NOT NULL
```

Done in program R (package sqldf)

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the usage of `convert()`

Comment: Is your example a single value (with the quotation marks included) or does that example indicate multiple rows with contents between each quotation mark being a value on one row?

Comment: Are the blank ones null or a blank space?

Comment: The quotation marks are included and the example above is just a part of the column named code (so each row/instance of the database consists of exactly one code element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all columns are valid integers, you could use:

```
select * , cast(code as int) IntCode
from base 
where code <> ''
```

To prevent cases when field `code` is not a valid number, use:

```
select *, cast(codeN as int) IntCode
from base
cross apply (select case when code <> '' and not code like '%[^0-9]%' then code else NULL end) N(codeN)
where codeN is not null
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6ab10/6)

**UPDATE**

To find rows where code is not a valid number, use

```
select * from base where code like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: @ABC I have changed my answer to prevent cases when code is not a valid number

Comment: Both suggestions aren't working out. The resulting elements are still strings (characters).

Comment: I have changed the query. You just need to convert the archer to int

Comment: Is there a change that this 'apply' function doesn't work in R (postgresql)?

Comment: @n: Note that `IsNumeric()` return true for all of these strings: '.' (ie single period), ',' (ie single comma), and '1e10', as they are valid *numeric* representations. A better test of whether a string contains only digits is `case when Value not like '%[^0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end as IsNumeric`

Comment: Updated as your comments. Tks a lot.

Comment: Cross Apply only works in SQL Server (you have a tag sql-server). Aren't you using it?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Went too fast with the sql tags. I'm gonna select this as the right answer. Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from base
where col like '[1-9]%'
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f7626/2/0

If you don't need to test for the number being valid, ie. a string such as '909XY2' then this may run marginally faster, more or less depending on the size of the table

Comment: But the query `select * from base where code <> ''` would be even faster, right?

Comment: @nizam did not think of that, is probably the simplest of the 2 as far as syntax goes, but both ways would probably perform equally as well. the execution plan would likely be identical, w/ just one table scan

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT (case when code not like '%[^0-9]%' then cast(code as int) end)
FROM   base 
WHERE code <> '' and code not like '%[^0-9]%';
```

The conditions are repeated in the `where` and `case` on purpose.  SQL Server does not guarantee that `where` filters are applied before logic in the `select`, so you can get an error with conversions.  More recent versions of SQL Server have `try_convert()` to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using sqldf with the default sqlite database and this test data:

```
 DF <- data.frame(a = c("7500", "4460", "", "2900", "2640", "1850", "", "2570", 
                        "9050", "8000", "9600"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

try this:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select cast(a as aint) as aint from DF where length(a) > 0")
```

giving:

```
  aint
1 7500
2 4460
3 2900
4 2640
5 1850
6 2570
7 9050
8 8000
9 9600
```

**Note** In plain R one could write:

```
transform(subset(DF, nchar(a) > 0), a = as.integer(a))
```